# Modal window in blade template shows all records instead of selected ID(s)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have table on page which list all orders which user has. Each order can have 1 or more attached documents and a button for download. Basically if the user has 2 orders he will have 2 buttons on his page

```
<a href="#files-{{ $download->order_id }}">Download</a> // order 1
<a href="#files-{{ $download->order_id }}">Download</a> // order 2
```

Clicking on the button is open modal window with files listed and link to download.

This is the modal window

```
        <span id="start" class="target"></span>
        <span id="files-{{ $download->order_id }}" class="target"></span>
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="content vertical-align-middle">
                <h2>Click on the button to download it</h2>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                  <thead id="tblHead">
                    <tr>
                      <th align="center">File</th>
                      <th align="center">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    @foreach($downloadableOrders as $files)                     
                        @if($files->status == 1)
                            {{--*/ $ids = explode(",", $files->docname); /*--}}
                            @foreach ($ids as $id)
                                <tr>
                                  <td></td>
                                  <td><a href="{{ URL::to('/files/download/' . $id . '?_token=' . csrf_token()) }}">Download</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <a class="close-btn" href="#start">X</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the query which is used

```
$downloadableOrders = Order::where('user_id', getCurrentUser()->user_id)
               ->select("orders.*",\DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(documents.id  ) as docname"))
               ->leftjoin("documents",\DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(documents.id,orders.order_downloadable)"),">",\DB::raw("'0'"))
               ->groupBy("orders.order_id")
              ->paginate(10);
```

The problem is that when modal is open it's lists all orders and all files. Should list files only for the clicked order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to open the modal box using ajax. So what you need to do is when you click on the Download link ajax will execute, get the data and show it in the modal box.

Comment: Is there an option without ajax? This modal doesn't use JS at all

Comment: The modal can also be opened using js syntax. For ex - $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

So try what I said in my answer and on ajax success you can open the modal box using above syntax.

Comment: Sorry, the point is that I don't want to use JS at all. That's why I use this modal of pure CSS/HTMl

Comment: Than somehow you'll have to find a way to pass "order id" in your "where clause", the best way according to me is to use Ajax.

Comment: Yes, thats the initial question how to `somehow` pass that order_id. There is no option to use ajax here. Thanks anyway